# Contribution to CAGR

Tags: cagr

Assume a timeseries of returns for which you calculate a CAGR.

How do you determine the **proportional** contribution of any subset of monthly returns to the overall CAGR like below?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps calculate the CAGR with and without that subset and examine the difference?

Comment: Agree and then to get the proportion just divide the differences by total cagr?

Comment: Probably. I have no experience with this, just a thought based on common sense.

Comment: Thank you Richard, I'm unsure myself